# Как вывести отфильтровать items по дате - detailDate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'date'

Tags: django

Есть ссылка `All`. Кликая на нее я получаю все даты по которым добавлены какие-либо `todo-items`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выглядит это так

- views.py

  ```
  def allDates(request):
     date = Todo.objects.extra(select={'custom_dt': 'strftime("%d-%m-%Y", "created_at")'}).values_list('custom_dt', flat=True).order_by('-custom_dt').distinct()
     return render(request, 'todo/alldates.html', {'date':date})
  ```
- alldates.html

  ```
  {% for dat in date %}
     <a href="{% url 'detaildate' %}"><h1>{{ dat }}</h1></a>
  {% endfor %}
  ```

Затем я кликаю на ссылку для того чтобы получить определённые айтемы созданные в эту дату, например 31-10-18 и я хочу их посмотреть

- views.py

  ```
  def detailDate(request, date):
     detail = Todo.objects.filter(created_at=date)    
     return render(request, 'todo/detaildate.html', {'detail':detail})
  ```
- detaildate.html

  ```
  {% for det in detail %}
     {{ det }}
  {% endfor %}
  ```

И при переходе по ссылке я получаю

```
detailDate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'date'
```

Я понимаю что он ожидает аргумента `date`, но я его не передаю. Как его передать. Как пофиксить эту ошибку и получать айтемы созданные в определённую дату ?

Answer (score 0):

> Я понимаю что он ожидает аргумента date, но я его не передаю. Как его передать.

Вам нужно правильно построить `url`, с его помощью вы сможете передать в `detailDate` дату. 
[Вот небольшие примеры](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#example) с доки, изучайте.